Go - how to read a large file into chunks and process using multithreading, and aggregate results
I have a very large CSV file that won't fit entirely into memory. I want to be able to read the file into chunks, and then chain a series of operations together to process the results. Lastly, I need to aggregate the final results together, maintaining the original order of the data.
The operations are the sort like GetColumns(start int, end int) , GetRows(start int, end int), SumRows(), etc. Thus, I might have the following code:
err := Read("input.csv").
        With(GetColumns(3, 5)).
        With(GetRows(7, 20)).
        With(SumRow()).
        Write("output.csv")

Is it possible to use goroutines to process the data at each operation? How do I pass the data from each operation, and lastly how do I take the final results and write them to a file while maintaining the original order of the data?
In the case of just reading the whole file into memory, I figured I'd need an interface and struct like so:

type TableProcessor struct {
    Operations []TableOperation
}

type TableOperation interface {
    Apply(table [][]string) [][]string
}

func (tp *TableProcessor) With(op TableOperation) *TableProcessor {
    tp.Operations = append(tp.Operations, op)
    return tp
}

And I figure each operation will have to look something like this:
func GetRows(start, end int) TableOperation {
    return &GetRowsOperation{Start: start, End: end}
}

type GetRowsOperation struct {
    Start, End int
}

func (op *GetRowsOperation) Apply(table [][]string) [][]string {
    return table[op.Start:op.End]
}

But I am not sure how the interfaces and structs should be if I am using chunking. And I really am not sure about how to incorporate goroutines into the mix.

What have you tried so far? Asking for a complete implementation often doesn’t result in an answer here. I can say that you can use an errgroup.Group to queue a bunch of go routines with easier error handling. Have one go routing read the file and send lines to the others via a channel. Hopefully that helps get you started.

I suggest you start with a simple csv.Reader that reads one record at time (don’t need entire CSV in memory). You can select the columns you want, and aggregate values from specific rows. Get something simple working first, then, once you have a metric like, “it takes two hours and I need it to run in 2 minutes”, you can start thinking about multiple goroutines.

Probably you want to have an apply function on your TableProcessor that will apply all the array of TableOperations but i think some of TableOperations can not be apply with goroutines like GetRows it.
so i added UseGoRoutine field to check if TableOperation should use GoRoutine or not and have the below code:
func (tp *TableProcessor) Apply() [][]string {
    // read the table from csv
    var table [][]string
    for i, op := range tp.Operations {
        if tp.UseGoRoutines[i] {
            table = processChunks(table, 1, op.Apply)
        } else {
            table = op.Apply(table)
        }
    }

    return table
}

then for processChunks:
func processChunks(arr [][]string, chunkSize int, function applyFunc) [][]string {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    output := make([][][]string, len(arr))

    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i += chunkSize {
        end := i + chunkSize
        if end > len(arr) {
            end = len(arr)
        }

        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int, chunk [][]string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            output[i] = function(chunk)
        }(i, arr[i:end])
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return function(flatten(output))
}

note that you should call the apply function.
i think you can not use this function with goroutines on all kind of operation but in some cases like sum and ... it works
i used 3D array because you said it is important to preserve the order of the rows.
then i used the below function to make 3D array flatten:
func flatten(arr [][][]string) [][]string {
    var arr2D [][]string
    for _, layer := range arr {
        for _, innerArr := range layer {
            arr2D = append(arr2D, innerArr)
        }
    }

    return arr2D
}

